# AngularJS dynamically creating elements with directives ($compile) and using a singleton service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm currently having a problem with angularJS (or my understanding of it - I come from a C# background)

I'm working on a project which requires elements to be dynamically created (cloned from the consequence of being dragged 'n dropped on page). Once these elements are dropped I want them to be able to be double clicked and a modal appear. I'm giving them a custom directive (openmodal) and then running them through the angular compile service.

This all works great...

However I need them to be able to access a service (I have a service as a proxy to a list of objects), however after being run through the $compile service they do not have access to the same objects. I am using the angular.injector methods to get the compile service for the current angular app so I can't see why its not using the same instance of the service (a new instance of the service gets created when the element above is run through $compile).

I'm sure its a problem in my understanding of how it/scopes work. However I've found this very difficult to search for given that the word "compile" is also used when declaring a directive (contains compile and link functions) and they're the links that appear most.

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/2x4zgV7xysSp48bSLrIW?p=preview) demonstrating my issue. If you click the "Add number" button a few times (both directives will show the same number as they are using the same service), however after clicking "Create Directive" and clicking "Click to show modal", the modal says the array length is 0.

I'm pretty sure its something to do with the way I am creating the modal from javascript.

```
function CreateModalDirective() {
      var compileService = angular.injector(['ng', 'numbersApp']).get('$compile');
      var scope = angular.element("#divForModal").scope();
      console.log(scope);
      var element = '<div id="theModalContainer" openmodal ng-click="OpenMyModal()">Click to show the modal</div>';
      var linkFn = compileService(element);
      var content = linkFn(scope);
      angular.element('#' + 'divForModal').append(content);
    }
```

The "FirstController" and "SecondController" just demonstrate that they are using the same service, the randomId parameter on the "ModalController" just demonstrates that I am able to pass through a number to the controller.

If however it's not possible doing this from a "pure JS function" then I may have to look at restructuring in order to achieve this functionality - again pointers would be great!!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after probably my 4th day of wrestling with this issue, I've figured out what was happening.

As @getOffMyLawn said the modal controller was using an entirely new $rootScope.
However it wasn't the $modal.open function from the angular-ui-bootstrap which was creating a new app.
Instead it was the way I was retrieving (or thought I was retrieving) the injector using `angular.injector(['ng', 'appNameHere'])`

After reading [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) (a bit more closely) it seems that I was not retrieving the injector for my app by using the code above, instead I was creating an entirely new app - which was then creating its own instance of the arrayNumbers service.

So to retrieve the injector for my app the code looks like this:
// Uses jQuery selectors (only if jQuery it has been included on page)

```
angular.element('#idOfMyAppElement').injector();
```

That now retrieves the injector for my app and I can go on and use the compile service and its instance of the arrayNumbers Service will be injected to the ModalController - so they all link up.

The full code for the working version of function CreateModalDirective() is now:

```
function CreateModalDirective(){
    var $injector = angular.element('#theApp').injector();
    var element = '<div id="theModalContainer" openmodal ng-click="OpenMyModal()">Click here for modal!</div>';
    $injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile){
        angular.element('#' + 'divForModal').append($compile(element)($rootScope));
    });
}
```

Comment: is there any way to pass any object which inside the scope to compile function instead of scope. for Ex. I have $scope.myCustomVal={key1:"val1"}; now I want to use like this: $compile(elm)($scope.myCustomVal); I want to set the same scope, just need to render only one key and the key is dynamically generated

Comment: yes, you can create a new scope before you compile and add properties there. for example 
var myNewScope = $rootScope.$new(); 
myNewScope.myCustomVal = { key1: "val1" }; 
$compile(elm)(myNewScope);

that will compile the element with the scope you have just created and added the "myCustomVal" to

Comment: I cant create new scope as it will difficult to destroy. and I want to create such directives dynamically so its template will get rendered using $scope.myCustomVal. I just want to render template with values of $scope.myCustomVal. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found the problem is that the `$modal.open` function is creating entirely new app, and when you have new app you also have new instance of services. Here's why I think so. When I `console.log` the rootScope in the testing controllers, the `openmodal` directive's link function and in the `CreateModalDirective` function, they all print out the same rootScope, however logging the rootScope in the controller you pass to `$modal.open` function gives **different** rootScope, and since one angular app can have only one rootScope, this means we have two different apps hence you can't see the services results since these are two different instances of the same service. Here's a modified [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qEbTUJyMzBFaCK3fJh03?p=preview) showing the things I said.

Comment: thanks for looking, you were on the right track - they were two totally different $rootScopes, however I was the culprit as I was creating a new app using angular.injector(['ng', 'numbersApp']) - turns out you have to go to the element where your app is and then call the .injector() function on it (see my answer) - much like the way you can retrieve scopes for certain elements too!